# Switch between different sized JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

To keep things short, I know how to switch between different `JPanels` using `CardLayout` and only using one `JFrame` but I want to know how, if it is possible, to have different sized `JPanels` occupying the `JFrame`. `CardLayout` uses the largest of the panels but I was wondering if there was any way to suppress that or override so that I could add different `JPanels` to a `JFrame` that were different sizes. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class View {

    //Views 
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel container;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private CardLayout layout;


    private final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private final int HEIGHT = 720;


    public View(){
        init();
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(container);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void init(){
        JButton button = new JButton();
        layout = new CardLayout();
        container = new JPanel(layout);
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();

        panel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        panel1.add(button);

        panel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        container.add(panel1, "panel1");
        container.add(panel2, "panel2");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                layout.show(container, "panel2");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        View view = new View();

    }


}
```

I put the JButton in the init method because I need it for future use and wanted to make sure now that it could be done.

Comment: have you tried setting minimumSize on the panels and calling frame.pack() after they are switched?

Comment: I will now, so what Im going to do is instead of setting the preferred size I will use my values to set the minimum size of the JPanels and after I do layout.show(container, "panel2"); I should call frame.pack()

Comment: I set the minimum size but that just made a very small frame....

Comment: hm.. then just let the preferredSize and pack. :D

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesnt work!

Comment: bugger.. give me a moment to get the example running on my pc. :)

Comment: IMHO - Changing the size of the window is annoying from the point of view of the user, especially as I might have sized the window to the size I want to  use and know you've gone and screwed that up

Comment: Wasn't sure if I should make my login page huge though

Comment: a large login window is a common design for applications. You an fill in the extra space with a logo, or a picture of cats. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way it seems to work with the cardLayout is by setting the preferred size of the container panel after the button is clicked.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            layout.show(container, "panel2");
            container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            frame.pack();
        }
    });
```

It's not a very great solution but it's pretty simple.

If a login window is what you need I would definitely recommend using 2 frames, just seems more logical.

Comment: @programmer,  If you use a CardLayout then the panels should be the same size. You should NOT be hardcoding the preferred size of the container. The whole point of using layout managers is to let each component determine its own preferred size. If you don't want the panels the same size then you swap out panels as I suggested  (You were give simple steps to follow).

Answer (score 2):

For a quick solution try two separate JFrames, or resize the frame to the size of the panel on button press.

Comment: I would have used two separate frames but teacher said not to, and yes desperate times causes for desperate measures XD

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a CardLayout. So you need to manage the visible panel yourself.

The logic would be something like:

```
JPanel content = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
content.removeAll();
content.add( theOtherPanel );
frame.pack();
```

So the idea is you only have one panel added to the content pane at a time and you need to swap it by doing the remove and add before you pack the frame so the frame is displayed at the size of each panel.

The question is why do you want to do this? Users don't like to see the size of the frame continually changing.

Comment: I need a small login frame and then have it go into something bigger for my application, not sure if I want to have the login frame super big. Thanks for the answer I will try it

Comment: Got rid of card layout, two panels appear at once and when I press the button panel1 goes away

Comment: `two panels appear at once` - well did you read the suggestion to only have a single panel added to the frame at once.